# Change image during onclick event in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

In my mobile app I want to change an image when a user tap on it.
So with a directive, I add a class to that element when the touchstart is fired, and I remove it when the touchend event is fired.
This class contains only:
    content: url("../img/image_active.png");

This works, but the first time that the application is started, it takes time to load the new image, and so for a moment (few millisecond), when I click on the image, I can not show no one image.
This appends only the first time.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can load img when app it's loaded, and by javascript change style content.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if (document.images) {
        img1 = new Image();

        img1.src = "path/from/img.png";
    }
    var element = document.getElementById('element');
    element.addEventListener('touchstart',function(){
       element.style.content = 'url("'+img1.src+'")';
    },false);
    element.addEventListener('touchend',function(){
        element.style.content = '';
    },false);
},false);
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Yes, in fact the standard way to do is, to pre-load the image with an img tag. If it gets opimised away by the WebView, you can try to put it in the html, and hide it.